# Another characterization of the supremum of a set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

$u$ is an upper bound of a set $E \subset S$ if given any $\epsilon >0$, there is $\delta \in E $ such that $u - \epsilon < \delta$.

PROBLEM:

An upper bound $u$ of $E \subset S$ ($E \neq \varnothing$) is the supremum of $E$ iff for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta \in E$ such that $u - \epsilon < \delta $.

#### my try:

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given. Write $ u = \sup E$. $u - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound and so by definition there is a $0 < \delta  \in E$ so that $u - \epsilon < \delta$.

Conversely, Say $u \in S$ is an upper bound of $E$. Now, suppose $v \in S$ and $v < u$. We show that $v$ is not an upper bound of $E$. In other words, we must find some $s \in E$  such that $v < s$. Notice $u - v > 0$ and with this choice of $\epsilon = u - v$ we can find $\delta $ in $E$ (By hypothesis) such that

$$ u - \epsilon < \delta \iff v < \delta $$

I would love to get some feedback. This is a homework assignment.

Hence, choosing $s = \delta$ shows that $v$ it not an upper bound of $E$. It follows that $u = \sup E $.

Comment: your definition of upper bound of $E$ seems to be independent of $E$

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I meant that before you've edited the question, $\delta$ was any positive number. Now the definition is still incorrect.

Comment: Why is it still incorrect? Do I have to require $E$ to be non empty?

Comment: The correct definition is as follows: $u$ is an upper bound of $E$ is $\delta < u$ for all $\delta \in E$. Do you see the difference? For example, if $E = [0,1]$ which $u$ satisfies your definition, but not an upper bound?

Comment: well, my book explicitly says that your definition of upper is equivalent with the one I wrote.

Comment: Say, $ u = 0.5$ in my example above. For any $\epsilon > 0$ we have that $ u - \epsilon < 0.5$ and hence for any $\epsilon$ we can take $\delta = 1$. So $u = 0.5$ is an upped bound of $[0,1]$.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But $u $ being an upper bound of $E$ implies that for any $\epsilon > 0$ theres $\delta \in E$ so that $u - \epsilon < \delta $ ?

Comment: No, if $u=2$ and $\epsilon = 0.1$ then $u-\epsilon = 1.9$ and there is no $\delta\in [0,1]$ satisfying $1.9 <\delta$

Answer (score 0):

An upper bound $u$ of $E \subset S$ ($E \neq \varnothing$) is the supremum of $E$ iff for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $u - \epsilon < \delta $.

Let $E=(-5,-4)$ and $u=-1$. Fix an $\epsilon >0$. In this case $u-\epsilon<\delta$, for all $\delta>0$ so can we say that $u$ is the supremum of $E$?